# Can't read array of structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am trying to read members of an object like in the code below.
The issue is that the code can't read the second member (car[i].model) in the array and the third one (car[i].price), only the first one (car[i].manufacturer).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct machine
{
    int price;
    char manufacturer[30];
    char model[30];
};


int main()
{
    int i = 0, n;
    printf("Introduce number of cars: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    struct machine car[100];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Data of the car nr. %d:\n", i+1);
        printf("Manufacturer: ");
        scanf_s("%s", car[i].manufacturer);
        printf("Model: ");
        scanf_s("%s", car[i].model); printf("\n");
        printf("Price: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &car[i].price); printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Data of the car nr. %d:\n", i + 1);
        printf("Manufacturer: %s\n", car[i].manufacturer);
        printf("Manufacturer: %s\n", car[i].manufacturer);
        printf("Model: %s\n", car[i].model);
        printf("Price %d\n", car[i].price);
    }


    _getch();
}
```

Comment: "The issue is that the code can't read ", wnat does that mean, doesn't compile, fails at run time, gives wrong result,...

Comment: At run time I can read only car[i].manufacturer. It skips reading car[i].model and car[i].price.

Comment: You need to read a [`scanf_s` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), because you're using it wrong and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Can we have a little taste of the input?

Comment: The program is working for me with regular scanf. The problem is maybe coming from your scanf_s function.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 requires to use scanf_s instead of scanf.

Comment: "Require! is the wrong word, you can easily disable the *warning* by adding a special macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf_s` requires the buffer size to be specified for input parameters with format `%s`. The buffer size includes the terminating null. Adapt your code like this:

```
struct machine
{
    int price;
    char manufacturer[30];
    char model[30];
};

struct machine car[100];
....
scanf_s("%s", car[i].manufacturer, 30 );
                                // ^^ buffer size
....    
scanf_s("%s", car[i].model, 30 );
                        //  ^^ buffer size
....
scanf_s("%d", &car[i].price);  // no buffer size
```